# Can't get bootstrap tooltips to show

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

In the following (very simple) example, I can't get bootstrap's tooltips to show, they just don't work (I get plain vanilla browser toooltips).

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zqgaMY

My A tags have to official bootstrap code:

```
data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Tooltip on left"
```

and I load the JS :

```
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
})
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include `jQuery` for the tooltips to work. Add this:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
```

**ABOVE** your `bootstrap.js` link and it should work fine.

---

Link to jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e0d8my79/104/

Link to CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oxKyKB

Comment: Yes. When there's an error like this it's usually instantly seen in the developer console of whatever browser.

Comment: This is great !! Not sure why it isn't clearer in the bootstrap docs, I'll re-read them to see where I missed it. Thanks a lot, I'll accept your answer as soon as SO allows me to.

Comment: @AlexandreDanault Glad I could help. Cheers!!

Answer (score -1):

Check your Jquery.js document is ready on the doom ... 
and make a proof ... 
only whit a   $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();